# How to programatically make RelativeLayout that works

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have a problem with creating a working Layout in View class that will not crush the program. I think everything is done correctly in the code, but probably there are some setting I don't know about I hope that You guys will reveal that to me.

I am trying to do drawing View with a "Clear" button and RadioGroup.

So first od all, that works fine, but both added content Views (btnReset = "Clear", btnScale = RadioGroup) are hoovered on each other. That is why I want to add one parent Layout, so I can easily manage these Views.

File1.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    DrawView tv = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
    addContentView(tv.btnScale, tv.paramsRadio);}
```

DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    public Button btnReset;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsRadio;
    public RadioGroup btnScale;

 public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    btnScale = new RadioGroup(context);
    btnScale.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   paramsRadio = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I omit most of the code because I think its irrelevant, everything works fine but the layout.

Anyway, when I try to create a layout, I simply add a little code:

Changed File1.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    DrawView tv = new DrawView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    addContentView(tv.layout, tv.params); }
```

Changed DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    public Button btnReset;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsRadio;
    public RelativeLayout layout;
    public RadioGroup btnScale;

 public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    btnScale = new RadioGroup(context);
    btnScale.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   paramsRadio = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   layout.addView(btnReset, params);
   layout.addView(btnScale, paramsRadio);
```

I assume that should work like charm, but unfortunately, when I try to do anything with newly created layout, my app crashes. What is wrong with that code?

Comment: wrong, wrong, wrong, you should extend ViewGroup not View

Comment: Nothing changed after extending ViewGroup instead of View. Effect is the same, it crushes because of layout.addView even if there is unchanged File1.java

Comment: and why do you need a custom view at all?

Comment: I need this because I have nice drawing code in there, not mentioned in my question

Comment: so define your RelativeLayout in xml and add it to your custom FrameLayout where you just override dispatchDraw

Comment: Never used dispatchDraw before, I will need some time to work it out and check Your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after quite long fight I managed to solve my own problem :D I did not do it, like @pskink suggested, because honestly for me it was too advanced. I found much simpler solution.

The thing is, You can create as much views as You want in DrawView.java, but sort them in Layout created in File1.java!

Just like that: 
File1.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
     LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  
     DrawView tv = new DrawView(this);
     ll.addView(tv.btnReset, tv.params);
     ll.addView(tv.btnScale, tv.paramsRadio);
     ll.addView(tv);
     setContentView(ll);
```

And DrawView.java stays the same:

```
 public class DrawView extends View {

    public Button btnReset;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsRadio;
    public RadioGroup btnScale;

 public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);

    btnReset = new Button(context);
    btnReset.setText("Clear Screen");

    btnScale = new RadioGroup(context);
    btnScale.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   paramsRadio = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```